# Which libraries are available via ffi for texlive luatex with no other installation?

Tags: luatex, texlive, ffi

Recent versions of `luatex` (≥ 1.0.3) come with [ffi](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html). That means that one can call a C library from lua inside a TeX file. [Some](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403794/8425) ([very](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475381/8425)) [recent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474443/8425) [examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429994/8425) on TeX.sx have proven its power.

Assuming current TeXlive (2018) or next release (TeXlive 2019), what libraries can be accessed with no additional installation from the user (from a package writer point of vue)?

Comment: I have written a couple of more answers on LuaTeX FFI than you linked: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A10995+LuaTeX+FFI

Comment: On GitHub I have some Gists using FFI: [Call other scripting languages from LuaJIT via FFI](https://gist.github.com/hmenke/2d57a3aa1d3d59a265f935dd4b384c36) and [Render an SVG image as PDF using librsvg2 and cairo](https://gist.github.com/hmenke/9facc3fe5ede9ed46c1838a919f7376f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without additional installation only the symbols from LuaTeX itself and its dynamically linked libraries are accessible.  However, the interesting question is which *symbols* are accessible which I will show in the following.

## Finding symbols

The tools `nm` and `ldd` I use below should be available on any POSIX system.  On Windows you'd use [`dumpbin.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference) tool for these jobs.

You can find a list of symbols using the `nm` tool.  The `grep ' T '` filters only symbols in the `text` section of the executable (i.e. only functions are shown).  Because in TeX Live 2018 there is some C++ code linked into LuaTeX you have to use the `--demangle` option to get something human readable.

```
$ nm -D --demangle `which luatex` | grep ' T '
[...huge list...]
```

I'm not sure how useful this is.  I have never called a function from the LuaTeX executable.

To find the dynamically linked libraries you can use the `ldd` tool.

```
$ ldd `which luatex`
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4d118000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007faa4ba0d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007faa4b66f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007faa4b27e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007faa4bc11000)
```

The symbols defined by these libraries can be looked up using the `nm` tool again but it's better to look in the corresponding documentation.  The libraries most useful to you are probably `libm.so.6` which is the C mathematical functions library ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math)) and `libc.so.6` which is the C standard library ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)).  On POSIX systems this includes the full POSIX C library ([reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/head.html)).

When using the FFI all these symbols are available through the `ffi.C` handle *without* loading a library using `ffi.load`.

## Cross-platform FFI code

If you restrict the set of functions you call via FFI to the C standard library the resulting code should be portable between POSIX systems and Windows.